# HBase RowKey Design based on Salting method

Tags: configuration, hbase

How can I configure the number of region in one RegionServer , and how I configure the number off StoreFiles on a Region using the hbase-site.xml file or others file on the configuration of hbase.

Comment: question title and body don't match? :/

Comment: Hi , the number of regions help me the know the number of split will hbase do for me in the automatic whay ,so it refers my design to storage of my data ,For exemple if i know the number of region possible on one Region server of my cluster i will design my row key ,the most used in reading data, in the Host1 for exemple .In other why the number of storeFile on region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I use the algorithm has `RegionSplitter` with
`HexAlgoritrhmSplitter`, this way I guarantee the knowledge of the position of my data pertinetes Thanks for help :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can precisely define those properties. Since HBase try to better control it for you according the data you have.

You can look on these properties:
hbase.regionserver.regionSplitLimit
hbase.regionserver.region.split.policy

Defining limits or policy for new region creation. I would suggest to take a look in default configuration and see what you can use to achieve your end goal.

Check:
https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-common/src/main/resources/hbase-default.xml

Comment: Thanks Nicolas , i will try to override the default config for this tow properties .